# Use Java RegEx to remove contents between paired hashtag ##

Tags: java, regex

In Java, is there a quicker way using regular expression to remove contents only in paired hashtag?
I will give some examples:

```
When user logs in ## //Expected Result: When user logs in ##
When user logs in #  //Expected Result: When user logs in #
When user logs in #the system# //Expected Result: When user logs in ##
When user logs in #the system  //Expected Result: When user logs in #the system
When user logs in #the system# named #test //Expected Result: When user logs in ## named #test
```

I have seen examples deleting contents in parentheses but this is a little different because "(" and ")" are different characters and if I simply use [replace](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm), compiler is not able to distinguish contents between `#the system#` and `#test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?!<#)#[^#]+#(?!#)", "##);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD6fY3/5)

Comment: #.*?#
would be another option!

Comment: I have used `#.+?#` in my solution instead of `#.*?#` because OP wants to leave `##` untouched.

Comment: Kind of works but When I input `"when ## ## abc"` it removes the space between `"##"` and `"##"`.